# Generating face normals with the geometry shader

Tags: glsl, normals, geometry-shader

I'm trying to visualize the face normals for a mesh, using the geometry shader to generate lines represeting the normal vectors. My intention was to draw that line from the triangles centroid, extenting a certain amount in the normal's direction.

This is the vertex shader's code :

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vs_in_pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vs_in_normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 vs_in_texc;

out VS_OUT_GS_IN {
    layout (location = 0) vec3 pos;
    layout (location = 1) vec3 normal;
    layout (location = 2) vec2 texc;
} vs_out;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(vs_in_pos, 1.0f);
    vs_out.pos = vs_in_pos;
    vs_out.normal = vs_in_normal;
    vs_out.texc = vs_in_texc;
}
```

This is the geometry shader's code :

```
#version 450 core

layout (row_major) uniform;
layout (triangles) in;
layout (line_strip, max_vertices = 2) out;

in VS_OUT_GS_IN {
    layout (location = 0) vec3 pos;
    layout (location = 1) vec3 normal;
    layout (location = 2) vec2 texc;
} gs_in[];

out GS_OUT_PS_IN {
    layout (location = 0) vec4 color;
    layout (location = 1) vec3 pos;
} gs_out;

layout (binding = 0) uniform transform_pack {
    mat4 model_view_projection;
};

uniform float normal_length;
uniform vec4 start_point_color;
uniform vec4 end_point_color;

void main() {

    const vec3 avg_normal = normalize(
        gs_in[0].normal + gs_in[1].normal + gs_in[2].normal);

    const vec3 triangle_centroid =
        (gs_in[0].pos + gs_in[1].pos + gs_in[2].pos) / 3.0f;

    {
        gl_Position = model_view_projection * vec4(triangle_centroid, 1.0f);
        gs_out.color = start_point_color;
        gs_out.pos = triangle_centroid;
        EmitVertex();
    }

    {
        const vec3 end_pt = triangle_centroid + avg_normal * normal_length;
        gl_Position = model_view_projection * vec4(end_pt, 1.0f);
        gs_out.pos = end_pt;
        gs_out.color = end_point_color;
        EmitVertex();
    }

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

My problem is that the line representing the face normal has the origin 
at one of the triangle's vertices (not the centroid).

If, however, I change this line

```
const vec3 triangle_centroid =
    (gs_in[0].pos + gs_in[1].pos + gs_in[2].pos) / 3.0f;
```

with this line

```
const vec3 triangle_centroid = 
    (gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz + gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz 
    + gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz) / 3.0f;
```

the line representing the normal has the origin at the centroid (as it should).

But I really have no ideea why the first approach does not produce the correct
result.

Some screenshots :

first method (wrong):

[image: first method (wrong)]

second method (correct):
[image: second method (correct)]

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've discovered that if I remove the layout qualifiers from the input/output blocks, like this

```
out VS_OUT_GS_IN {
     vec3 pos;
     vec3 normal;
     vec2 texc;
} vs_out;
```

and like this in the geometry shader

```
in VS_OUT_GS_IN {
     vec3 pos;
     vec3 normal;
     vec2 texc;
} gs_in[];
```

it produces the expected results.

But why does it not work when the explicit layout qualifier is used for the individual members of the block ?

Answer (score 1):

Although according to the OpenGL standard you should be allowed to specify whichever location you want, some drivers have specific locations for legacy uses.

Specifying locations may cause conflicts with those.

For example: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php

> NVidia hardware indices are reserved for built-in attributes:
>
> gl_Vertex     0
>
> gl_Normal     2
>
> gl_Color  3
>
> gl_SecondaryColor     4
>
> gl_FogCoord   5
>
> gl_MultiTexCoord0     8
>
> gl_MultiTexCoord1     9
>
> gl_MultiTexCoord2     10
>
> gl_MultiTexCoord3     11
>
> gl_MultiTexCoord4     12
>
> gl_MultiTexCoord5     13
>
> gl_MultiTexCoord6     14
>
> gl_MultiTexCoord7     15

Comment: This is only a consideration if you're mixing generic attribs with legacy attribs; you can't do glVertexPointer and glVertexAttribPointer(0), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

With a triangle with 3 vertices, I was able to get the normal pretty easily in the geometry shader using this formula:

```
vec3 normal = cross(
    normalize(vec3(gl_in[1].gl_Position) - vec3(gl_in[0].gl_Position)),
    normalize(vec3(gl_in[2].gl_Position) - vec3(gl_in[0].gl_Position))
);
```

each `gl_in[].gl_Position` is a point on the triangle. You may have to make it negative if the points are in a different order.